# Scala Monoid[Map[A,B]]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monoids

I'm reading a book with the following:

```
sealed trait Currency
case object USD extends Currency
... other currency types

case class Money(m: Map[Currency, BigDecimal]) {
  ... methods defined
}
```

The discussion goes on to recognize certain types of operations on `Money` as being Monoidal so we want to create a `Monoid` for `Money`.  What comes next though are listings I can't parse properly.

First is the definition of `zeroMoney`.  This is done as follows:

```
final val zeroMoney: Money = Money(Monoid[Map[Currency, BigDecimal]].zero)
```

What I have trouble following here is the part inside the `Money` parameter list.  Specifically the

```
Monoid[Map[Currency, BigDecimal]].zero
```

Is this supposed to construct something?  So far in the discussion there hasn't been an implementation of the `zero` function for `Monoid[Map[A,B]]` so what does this mean?

Following this is the following:

```
implicit def MoneyAdditionMonoid = new Monoid[Money] {
  val m = implicitly(Monoid[Map[Currency, BigDecimal]])
  def zero = zeroMoney
  def op(m1: Money, m2: Money) = Money(m.op(m1.m, m2.m))
}
```

The definition of `op` is fine given everything else so that isn't a problem.  But I still don't understand what `zeroMoney` is given its definition.  This also gives me the same problem with the implicit `m` as well.

So, just what does `Monoid[Map[Currency, BigDecimal]]` actually do?  I don't see how it constructs anything since `Monoid` is a trait with no implementation.  How can it be used without defining `op` and `zero` first?

Comment: There is missing context in your question. We can't guess the answer without having read the book. Your question should be self-contained and complete for us to answer

Comment: @melston That approach is probably done better with squants or `joda-money`, libraries which already fully implement all the things you can possibly want. Maybe have a look there first? I know it doesn't directly answer your question but I can't help to think the code smells of future hassle for you.

Comment: @flavian he's probably just reading a book about design in Scala and tries to understand it. This is a question about the mechanisms of the language, not about the best way to work with currencies in Scala

Comment: Thanks, all.  Yes, I am reading the Manning book "Functional and Reactive Domain Modeling" and what I provided was what was discussed in the book so far.  I am not terribly proficient with Scala and this example confuses me, hence the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this code to compile, you would need something like the following:

```
trait Monoid[T] {
  def zero: T
  def op(x: T, y: T): T
}

object Monoid {
  def apply[T](implicit i: Monoid[T]): Monoid[T] = i
}
```

So `Monoid[Map[Currency, BigDecimal]].zero` desugars into `Monoid.apply[Map[Currency, BigDecimal]].zero`, which simplifies to `implicitly[Monoid[Map[Currency, BigDecimal]]].zero`.

`zero` in the Monoidal context is the element such that

```
Monoid[T].op(Monoid[T].zero, x) ==
Monoid[T].op(x, Monoid[T].zero) ==
x
```

In the case of `Map`, I would assume the `Monoid` combines Maps with `++`. The `zero` would then simply be `Map.empty`, which is what `Monoid[Map[Currency, BigDecimal]].zero` finally simplifies into.

**Edit: answer to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42600662/scala-monoidmapa-b/42601503?noredirect=1#comment72334666_42601503):**

Note that implicit conversion *is not used at all* here. This is the type class pattern which uses only implicit parameters.

> `Map[A, B]` is a `Monoid` if `B` is a `Monoid`

That's one way to do it, which is different from the one I suggested with `++`. Let's see an example. How would you expect the following maps to be combined together:?

- `Map(€ → List(1, 2, 3), $ → List(4, 5))`
- `Map(€ → List(10, 15), $ → List(100))`

The results you would expect is probably `Map(€ → List(1, 2, 3, 10, 15), $ → List(4, 5, 11))`, which is only possible because we know how to combine two lists. The `Monoid[List[Int]]` I implicitly used here is `(Nil, :::)`. For a general type `B` you would also need *something* to smash two `B`s together, this something is called a `Monoid`!

For completeness, here is the `Monoid[Map[A, B]]` I'm guessing the book wants to define:

```
implicit def mm[A, B](implicit mb: Monoid[B]): Monoid[Map[A, B]] =
  new Monoid[Map[A, B]] {
    def zero: Map[A, B] = Map.empty

    def op(x: Map[A, B], y: Map[A, B]): Map[A, B] =
      (x.toList ::: y.toList).groupBy(_._1).map {
        case (k, v) => (k, v.map(_._2).reduce(mb.op))
      }.toMap
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, @OlivierBlanvillain, I think I follow what you are saying.  The book does say that Map[A, B] is a Monoid if B is a Monoid, though I don't understand that statement.  If there is an implicit conversion of Map[A,B] to Monoid then I am unaware of it but I would expect that you probably have it right, here.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean when you say implicit conversion is not used but then to on to define an implicit conversion.  Also, if the Monoid you define is not already a part of Prelude (or somewhere else) then I don't see how the code in the book could work.  It is not provided anywhere and seems to assume that the `mm` you have here is implicitly available.  In any case, it seems that some kind of implicit must be used or the `m` in the Monoid in the original listing couldn't be created, right?

Comment: Ah, I found it and you are absolutely right.  I had to go to the online code repo and scavenge around to find it but there are actually a couple of implicit definitions of `Monoid[Map[K,V]]` that were not mentioned in the book (oddly enough both implemented the same way).  Thanks to your answer I had a better idea of what to look for.